# Why trigger click not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to put simple login form with enter key. The login functionality placed in login button click. I just trying to trigger it on keypress of enter button. But its not working. What is my problem?

```
  $("#userPassword").bind('keypress', function(e) {
       var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
       console.log("trigger outside "+code);
        if(code == 13) 
        {   
            console.log("trigger insided");
            $( "#loginBtn" ).trigger( "click" );

        }
     });
```

Comment: have you placed the above code in document.ready function? if not, do that

Comment: whats the issue you are getting when you click, any error in browser console ?

Comment: Implying that you are using the newest version of jQuery, I think that "bind" is deprecated and you should be using "on" instead.

Comment: make button type submit and it should post automatically on pressing enter key

Comment: @mulla.azzi yes i placed in ready function onlly

Comment: @coder no error in console... it simply reloads the page while am pressing enter key

Comment: @EhsanSajjad ... it works... even the both console dialogs are printing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you defined or handled the click event on the login button? If this isn't working, then I think you have not bind any function to the click handler and login is working some other way.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: It is my login button click function... what is wrong with this?
$("#loginBtn").click(function(){
//mycode

});

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make your code run when user presses "Enter" in any of the field in your login form then you are doing it wrong. 
The proper way is to wrap your login/password fields and submit button into a form and write a form on submit handler.